# Execute a JavaScript function when I have its name as a string - Not working

Tags: javascript

I need to call a function via a var string.  I see that this question has been asked before: 
[How to execute a JavaScript function when I have its name as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string)

But the solution is not working.  Did I do something wrong?
https://jsfiddle.net/puLh9keg/

```
// a.callThis is the function that will be called using var string
var a = {
  callThis:
     function (ok, param1, param2) {
            alert(ok + "|" + param1 + "|" + param2);
        }
}

// Below is from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string 
function executeFunctionByName(functionName, context /*, args */) {
  var args = [].slice.call(arguments).splice(2);
  var namespaces = functionName.split(".");
  var func = namespaces.pop();
  for(var i = 0; i < namespaces.length; i++) {
    context = context[namespaces[i]];
  }
  return context[func].apply(context, args);
}


// try call a.callThis by var string
var fn = 'a.callThis';
executeFunctionByName(fn, window, true, 'param1', 'param2');
```

Comment: Please tell us what you mean by "not working."

Comment: Look at how your code is being added to the result window (use dev tools) you will see you arent using the correct JSFiddle settings to make this work

Comment: your `var a` is not in global scope - change to `window.a =` - or ensure that your JS is not running "on load" but "no wrap in body" or "no wrap in head"

Comment: Don't pass functions around using their names. In JavaScript, you can pass the function **itself** around, since functions are first-class objects. However, you may need to ensure the function is bound to the proper `this`.

Comment: *I need to call a function via a var string.* Why? Don't pass functions around using their names. In JavaScript, you can pass the function **itself** around, since functions are first-class objects. However, you may need to ensure the function is bound to the proper `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works as written.  As multiple people have mentioned in comments, the reason your JSFiddle does not work is that you you have made the assumption that `window` is the global scope in which you are operating. However, you have set your JSFiddle JavaScript to run `onLoad`.  This wraps it in a `onload` handler.  Thus, contrary to your assumption, your code is not running with `window` as the global scope, which makes it not work.  You can get your code working on JSFiddle by changing the JavaScript `LOAD TYPE` option to either `No wrap - in <head>` or `No wrap - in <body>`.

Here is a [JSFiddle that has that change implemented](https://jsfiddle.net/hjscvcu7/).

Also, below is your code in a snippet, which is working fine.

```js
// a.callThis is the function that will be called using var string
var a = {
  callThis:
     function (ok, param1, param2) {
            alert(ok + "|" + param1 + "|" + param2);
        }
}

// Below is from 
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788
//      /how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string 
function executeFunctionByName(functionName, context /*, args */) {
  var args = [].slice.call(arguments).splice(2);
  var namespaces = functionName.split(".");
  var func = namespaces.pop();
  for(var i = 0; i < namespaces.length; i++) {
    context = context[namespaces[i]];
  }
  return context[func].apply(context, args);
}


// try call a.callThis by var string
var fn = 'a.callThis';
executeFunctionByName(fn, window, true, 'param1', 'param2');
```